# Jquery form hide/show div element

Tags: jquery-ui, effects

I have little problem with some jquery execution. I have one div which i want to hide and show with link.

```
$("#butt_form").click(function(){
    if ($("#site_form").is(":hidden"))
        $("#site_form").slideDown(300);
    else
        //$("#site_info").hide();
        $("#site_form").slideUp(300);

<div class='info_block' id='site_form'>
****************************
</form></div>



<a href='' id='butt_form' class='no'>form: ON</a>
```

The problem is that it begin and before end i think it stop and doesn't hide.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/6446/ here it works.

Comment: If it works there, then it must be how you are including the jQuery files. You should post your entire markup with unnecessary parts left out.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/test/include/scripts.js"></script>

<div class='info_block' id='site_form'>
<form action="{$smarty.const.BASE_PATH}/images/upload/" method="post" name="add_form" >************
</form></div>
<br />
<div id='box_top'>
<div style='float:right;'>
<a href='' id='butt_info' class='no'>info: ON</a>
<a href='' id='butt_form' class='no'>form: ON</a>

Comment: I meant where you click edit on your question and post everything there in code blocks so it's easy to read. ;)

Comment: Sorry i am noob here :))) Next time i will know. Thanks again Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try slideToggle (http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)?

```
$("#butt_form").click(function () {
  $("#site_form").slideToggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Cool but this also doesn't fix my problem it just move a little and then go back. May be the issue is somewhere in me.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="****/include/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: Not sure what you've written there but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/J9V7C/ - works fine. Maybe something to do with your CSS, jQuery needs to figure out the element height to slide in and out.

Comment: Ok the problem was that i forget to put return FALSE; after slideToggle

Comment: @bob - Oops, I put that in the jsfiddle I linked to but not above. I've corrected it above too to show the correct answer. You should probably mark this as answered.